# Disable non-English characters?

Tags: html, text, non-english

One of my pages is bugged, I get a message from Google saying it's in Indonesian.
Here's a .txt link if you want: http://lc-roleplay.com/account/actions/modelchange/modelchange.txt

Can I somehow disable ALL non-English letters?

Comment: What does "is bugged" mean? *"is buggy"*? With all the in-page styles and inline styles there's too much to read. All the validation errors don't help either http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flc-roleplay.com%2Faccount.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0
Hint: for an HTML comment, `<!------- x` is **not** the same as `<!-- x` (two dashes only for both opening and closing comments)
Is something generating this, or can you move the styles into a `.css` file?

Comment: You can "disable" characters in a static document by deleting them.

Comment: Indonesian is one of the few languages that does not use letters other than basic Latin A to Z, so there is little sense that “non-English” characters caused the misclassification.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't.

There are no such thing as 'English letters'.  What you are describing are Roman characters, of which the 52 that appear in English also appear in most other languages.

Furthermore, many English words are written with foreign accents retained, as in café, naïve and façade.

The best you could do would be to run your inputs through an English spellcheck, and reject any input with a given percentage of spelling errors.

You could enforce ASCII encoding, but that would not prevent someone giving you unicode input - it would just mean that it was being improperly decoded (and would look like gibberish)